# I'm attempting to resize my background with media queries any suggestions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, background-image

I can't figure out how to resize my background image while using media query.  Does anyone have any suggestions or answers for this?  I've tried using media query for my background image the same way I've tried other media queries they usually work but for the background image it seems not to or I'm doing something wrong.  What the problem is that my background image doesn't fully show when using a smaller device and I want it to.  Any help I will greatly appreciate please, and thank you in advance.

```css
    body{
        background-image:url("codeback.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 1000px, 500px;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        
        
    }
    
    li{
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        text-align:right;
        font-size:20px;
    }
    
    h1{
        text-align:center;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:1000px;)
    {
        body
        {background-size: cover;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Evin McReynolds Portfolio</title>
  
  </head>

<body>
    <h1><strong>Hello welcome to Evin McReynolds portfolio</strong></h1>
    
<nav>
            <ul class="link">
                <li>Home</li></br>
                <li><a href="Aboutem.html">About Evin</a></li></br>
                <li><a href="contactem.html">Contact Evin</a></li></br>
                <li><a href="skillsem.html">Skills</a></li></br>
                <li><a href="EvinPro.html">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!important` to force the background-size to cover the entire screen.

```css
body{
        background-image:url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/03/4b/58/034b588b27ec7bc95cb7cb072da3fc60.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 1000px, 500px;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        
        
    }
    
    li{
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        text-align:right;
        font-size:20px;
    }
    
    h1{
        text-align:center;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px)
    {
        body{
        background-size: cover !important;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Evin McReynolds Portfolio</title>
  
  </head>

<body>
    <h1><strong>Hello welcome to Evin McReynolds portfolio</strong></h1>
    
<nav>
            <ul class="link">
                <li>Home</li></br>
                <li><a href="Aboutem.html">About Evin</a></li></br>
                <li><a href="contactem.html">Contact Evin</a></li></br>
                <li><a href="skillsem.html">Skills</a></li></br>
                <li><a href="EvinPro.html">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: does !important still apply when using pixels? for example:  @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px)
    {
        body{
        background-size: 500px !important;
        }
    }

Comment: @Emc `!important` can apply to any css attribute :)

Answer (score 0):

It can depend highly on how you are placing the image on the page.
You can do it with the img html tag or you could put it inside just any
div tag, and than use CSS to display it as a background image. I find
both methods can respond differently and not as you'd expect when attempting
to style.

You could have a series of images that are all static in size and have the file path change as it goes through the media sizes

Or.. have just 1 responsive image where it just scales down in size. You can get some interesting super-sampling going on with the resizing algorithm which can look very nice.

```
#supersampleimgDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(1650x3000px_responsiveImage.png);
}

#responsive_wCtrl_ImgDiv {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 63%;
  min-height: 20%;
  background-image: url(responsiveImage.png);
}
```

I'm not sure how ideal this method really is, it doesn't make
much sense for a phone to download such a large file over mobile
data when it could just be a smaller image served up in the
media query.

I'm not saying don't use responsive image, but its good to
understand where its faults are. What's nice is you could do
stuff like max-width: 500px or 63%; to control how it renders.
The height dimension automagically calculates to maintain image
aspect ratio.

```
#imgDiv{
  height: auto;
  width: 2000px;
  background-image: url(2000long_staticBg.png);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
  #imgDiv{
    height: auto;
    width: 1220px;
    background-image: url(1220long_staticBg.png);
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
   #imgDiv{
    height: auto;
    width: 440px;
    background-image: url(440long_staticBg.png);
  }
}
```

you can gain control of an image and how its displayed when your able to define 1 dimension (length or width) as static and the other as auto. Also use a min-max width and height to gain control as the site goes through the media queries.